# 'hasOne' association thorwing error [Nodejs, Sequelize]

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have two models described in Nodejs and Sequelize. I am trying to create an association `hasOne` between the two tables `'Creator'` and `'UserLogin'`. When I mention the association it throws error `Creator.hasOne called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model`.
I have posted the two tables and the association code below. Any help is really appreciated. I am new to Sequelize.

```
//Creator Model

'use strict';
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var Creator = sequelize.define(
        'Creator',
        {
            firstname: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
            lastname: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
        },
        {
            createdAt: 'created_at',
            updatedAt: 'updated_at',
            deletedAt: 'deleted_at',
            paranoid: true,
            underscored: true,
            tableName: 'creator',
        },
    );

    return Creator;
};

//UserLogin Model
'use strict';

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var UserLogin = sequelize.define(
        'UserLogin',
        {
            creator_id: {type:DataTypes.INTEGER},
            username: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
            password: {type:DataTypes.STRING},
            creatorfile: {type:DataTypes.STRING}

        },
        {
            createdAt: 'created_at',
            updatedAt: 'updated_at',
            deletedAt: 'deleted_at',
            paranoid: true,
            underscored: true,
            tableName: 'UserLogin',
        },
    );

    return UserLogin;
};

//Association Defining
global.db.Creator.hasOne(global.db.UserLogin, {
    onDelete: 'cascade',
    foreignKey: 'creator_id',
});
```

P.S: There are `hasMany` association between `'Creator'` table and other tables which is working. I defined `hasMany` association the same way I am trying to do `hasOne`. I am not sure why `hasOne` is throwing the error mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a stupid mistake. The `global.db` where I am mentioning all the models the key for `UserLogin` model was `Login` which is why it was throwing error. And I was trying to create association with `global.db.UserLogin`. Instead it will be `global.db.Login`

```
global.db = {
        Sequelize: Sequelize,
        sequelize: sequelize,
        Creator: require(__dirname + '/creator')(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes),
        Install: require(__dirname + '/install')(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes),
        Applications: require(__dirname+'/application')(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes),
        Login: require(__dirname+'/userlogin')(sequelize,Sequelize.DataTypes)
        /*
        *
        * TODO add any additional models here.
        *
        */
    };

//Association Defining
global.db.Creator.hasOne(global.db.Login, {
    onDelete: 'cascade',
    foreignKey: 'creator_id',
});
```